# RADIUS server and interface / configuration tools

Tags: user-interface, captive-portal

I am implementing WPA2-Enterprise AAA (Authentication, Authorization and Accounting) for a small .edu project and am looking for recommendations for an interface and maintenance tools.  More specifically on the Accounting side of things.

I am piloting a small Freeradius install now and it is a lot of work editing the config files manually.  Especially around limiting session amount and duration.

Requirements:

1. Run on Linux and fit on a Beaglebone Black (4GB flash, 512MB DDR3 SDRAM)
2. Docker image also an option
3. Handle ~50-100 users
4. Easy to configure amount/duration of user sessions

Note:  RADIUS tag needed but I don't have enough points yet...